# Make a fixed header in css?

Tags: css

I have 3 `ListBoxes` in Asp.net

On selection of the first `listbox` the second and third get populated each of them have a header

[image]

Sometimes the second Listbox may not be present that is when the css gets spoiled

[image]

**My CSS**

```
    .GroupHeader
{
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: Maroon;
    margin:0px;
    background-color: #EBEBEB;
    padding:4px 0px 4px 5px;
    line-height:20px;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    font-weight:bolder;
    width:240px;

}
```

**HTML**

**My p is inside a table division**

```
     <td valign="top" width="236px">
   <p class="GroupHeader" >
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Root Categories</p>
```

**DONE:** Just Had to use this code

```
  <td valign="top" width="236px">
   <p class="GroupHeader" style="width:236px;" >
  &nbsp;&nbsp;Root Categories</p>
```

Comment: Please show some HTML. Is the problem that the width isn't being applied when there are only two lists?

Comment: BTW: You should not be using TABLEs for layouts. You SHOULD be using header tags, not paragraphs, for headers.

Comment: is there no alternative way of solving the issue